# Windows Update (windows 7 64-bit): "failed" installation is a duplicate

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-update

## Duplicate update installation attempt by Windows Update

Windows Update (windows 7 64-bit) failed on 6/20/2014 to install the following update because this update was already successfully installed on ‎8/‎16/‎2012 as shown below. Automatic update keeps trying and failing to install the duplicate update. The "Fix IT" did not work.  What else to do if windows update keeps failing (causing Update Installation to freeze) to install, not knowing that the update was already successfully installed. Looking at the update history, I find the "failed" installation is duplicate.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 XML Editor (KB2251489)

Installation date: ‎6/‎20/‎2014 8:00 AM

Installation status: Failed

Error details: Code 80070050

Update type: Important

A security issue has been identified leading to an XXE (Xml eXternal Entity) vulnerability. You can protect your computer by installing this update from Microsoft.  After you install this item, you may have to restart your computer.

More information: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=195036

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 XML Editor (KB2251489)

Installation date: ‎8/‎16/‎2012 10:36 PM

Installation status: Successful

Update type: Important

A security issue has been identified leading to an XXE (Xml eXternal Entity) vulnerability. You can protect your computer by installing this update from Microsoft.  After you install this item, you may have to restart your computer.

Comment: You already have the update installed why are you trying to install it twice?

Comment: @Ramhound: It looks as if _automatic_ Windows Update (the recommended option) is trying to reinstall the update. This is a known caveat with some updates on some systems. Maybe go manual and purposefully unselect the problematic update?